# coordinates in R with height

Tags: r, dataframe, spatial

I have a dataset that has `longitude`, `latitude`, `HGTS`, and `Height` attributes. I know how to make a `Spatial` object with `coordinates()` function like :

```r
library(sp)
coordinates(data) <- ~longitude+latitude
```

but, since the `HGTS` attribute also depends on `height`, 
can I make it like this

```
coordinates(data) <- ~longitude + latitude + height
```

so it would be like a 3D coordinate? And is this the right approach?

Comment: Welcome! Best to always provide your data with `dput`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct - just try it out. Illustrating with the `meuse.grid` data since you're not providing your data:

```
df <- meuse.grid
df$height <- sample(c(0:10), nrow(df), replace = TRUE) # just adding a random third dimension
coordinates(df) <- ~ x + y + height
```